# Como editar scaffold en rails 7 para agregar mas valores a postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

recien comienzo con ruby on rails me gustaria saber si una vez definido el scaffold lo puedo editar para agregar mas campos a mis formularios y se guarden en la base de datos.

En mi codigo me gustaria modificar el orden en el que se muestren de esta manera

```
<%=form.label :persona %>
<%= form.select :persona, ["Natural", "Juridica"] %>

<%=form.label :documento %>
<%= form.text_field :documento%>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien a que te refieres, pero si quieres incluir campos nuevos en una tabla, tienes que [crear una migración](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration). Si no es eso, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar más detalles a qué te refieres con modificar el orden.

Answer (score 0):

claro que puedes editar la tabla que te crea el comando `scaffold`. Lo primero que debes de conocer es el nombre de tu modelo al cual  quieres agregar más campos, ejemmplo: `user` o `usuario`, pero esto lo tendras que poner en plural ejemplo `users` ó `usuarios`. Una vez identificado ejecutas el siguiente comando según sea el nombre de la tabla o modelo a agregar más campos o columnas:

```
rails generate migration add_address_to_users:string
```

Con este comando lo que haces es decirle que vas a agregar una nueva columna a la tabla `USERS` para el modelo `user.rb`, toma en cuenta que la columna `address` y `users`solo es de ejemplo tu puedes cambiarlo por el nombre que tenga tu tabla o modelo en este caso.

Y una vez ejecutado el comando mencionado anteriormente, ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
rails db:migrate
```

espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos.